# Flagging comments on deleted answers?

Tags: discussion, flagging, deleted-answer

In this [question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/85875/30492) there was an answer which got two comments (mine plus another) objecting that it was not answering the question.

The reaction of the poster was "sour"
[image]

Would it still make sense to flag it for the records, or since it has been cancelled it would not be considered?

Comment: As a general rule of thumb (although I don't have the privilege to do this) I would say that you should not do anything on deleted posts unless it's substantial. Regarding comments I would say that you should only flag them if they are incredibly rude to let moderators know of this behaviour, but for example flagging as *chatty* would be pretty much useless. It's already deleted. In this case I think it would be okay to leave. It's *not constructive* but he didn't insult anyone. He just (strongly) disagrees with you two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once a post is deleted, it's out of view of most visitors to the site -- only users with 10k rep who go that far down the page will see them.  So it's not super-important to flag those -- and, in fact, I didn't even know you *could* flag deleted comments, but I've learned that you can.  (Thanks for the science, Aify.)

If you see something super-bad, like personal attacks, feel free to flag anyway to let us know.  Most of the time, though, your (and our) attention is probably better directed elsewhere.

(In doing the science for this answer I ended up deleting that last comment.  Just saying this in case anybody else looks and is puzzled.)

Comment: I'm almost a bit sad to see myself have my first declined comment flag on record XD but it's alright, t'was in the name of science!

Comment: If we could reply to comment flags, I'd've given you something for the record to make that look better. :-)